# Docker Rails Tutorial generated files not exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, docker, missing-data

I am trying basic Docker & Rails tutorials on my windows10 home OS with Docker toolbox.

```
Client: 17.05.0-ce
Server: 17.06.0-ce
```

And hello-world tutorials works!

Now I am trying this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH6pcHb6Wug&lc=z12ocxayznynslzjj04chbtgiwbhuf4z5xk0k.1499518307572479

And everything looks okay until I check rails generated project files.
In terminal showing like files are generating but when I use the command 'ls -l' its show only my manually created files (4).

What's happening with Rails generated files?
Where they go?

Here is docker-compose.yml content:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/deep
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Here is Dockerfile content:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

ENV HOME /home/rails/deep

# Install PGsql dependencies and js engine
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

WORKDIR $HOME

# Install gems
ADD Gemfile* $HOME/
RUN bundle install

# Add the app code
ADD . $HOME
```

Here is my terminal at end: https://ibb.co/c2eqFF

I found the solution:
https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/508

Just need to place a .env file next to your docker-compose.yml file, with the following content : `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/508

Just need to place a `.env` file next to your docker-compose.yml file, with the following content : `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`